# Inserting checkbox entries into database

Tags: php, session, checkbox

I have checkboxes with name statuses.  This is how i am doing it:

```
   $_SESSION['statuses'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['statuses']);
```

When i insert it that is how i am doing it:

```
   $insert = "INSERT INTO submitted (statuses) 
   VALUES ('".$_SESSION['statuses']."')";

   $query = mysql_query($insert) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
```

Problem is nothing that is checked gets inserted into the database, so how do i insert checked entries?

NEW/UPDATE:

This is how the checkbox form looks like:

```
                    <input type="checkbox" name="statuses" value="something">
        <input type="checkbox" name="statuses" value="something">
        <input type="checkbox" name="statuses" value="something">
        <input type="checkbox" name="statuses" value="something">
        <input type="checkbox" name="statuses" value="something">
        <input type="checkbox" name="statuses" value="something">
```

Comment: Why are you using a `SESSION` variable to do this? And what is `$_POST['statuses']`? Is is it a one-to-one value?

Comment: this is from a 5 page form so i am using sessions.  $_POST['statuses']; is for checkboxes.

Comment: So it's part of a wizard. Is `name="statuses[]"` Is the value that you're trying to insert actually a string, or some other type of value (array, etc.)?

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the issue might lie in the mark up you have written for the form. Here's and example:

```
<form action="checkbox-form.php" method="post">
Select your options<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="A" />A<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="B" />B<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="C" />C<br />
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Notice that `options` is set as `options[]`. This allows an array of all checked options to appear in your POST super variable.

If you do:

```
var_dump($_POST['options']);
```

You should then get an array containing all the checked values.

Then you can do something like:

```
foreach($_POST['options'] as &$option){
   mysql_real_escape_string($option);
}
```

Then insert into the database:

```
   $insert = "INSERT INTO submitted (statuses)       
   VALUES ('". implode(",", $_POST['options']) ."')";      

   $query = mysql_query($insert) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
```

Update:
On each page of the form you should have something like escape the values and save it to the session. This then saves the values from each page to the user's session:

```
//Page 1
foreach($_POST['options'] as $option){
     $_SESSION['options'][] = mysql_real_escape_string($option);
}

//page 2
$_SESSION['SOME_OTHER_VALUE_FROM_TEXT_BOX'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SOME_OTHER_VALUE_FROM_TEXT_BOX');

//Final page:
//Everything is now stored in SESSION, so you can use them there:
//For example, display the value of options:
var_dump($_SESSION['options']); //etc

//So here, you would just run your sql queries to insert the appropriate data into your databse.
```

Comment: ok one thign when i use var_dump the values are showing up on the next page.  any way to prevent hat from showing to the user.

Comment: 'var_dump` prints the values out for you to see. This is used for debugging purposes. Just remove the var_dump line and you should be fine.

Comment: ok one problem, if i select all options there are bout 20 then it gives me a syntax check error but i can't find anything wrong..

Comment: The error should tell you which line is causing the problem. Can you post the line of code that is causing the error?

Comment: OK, i was able to fix that.  But how do i wrap this in a session if i use this on Page 4 of a 5 page form where the there is a 6th page that is used for processing all of the pages...? will be very helpful, been going crazy trying to make it work in a session.

Comment: All you have to do is then store that in your session: `$_SESSION['options'] = $_POST['options']`. Then when you are ready to save to the database (on the last page), change the foreach loop to run `mysql_real_escape_string()` on all the session variable, then structure your SQL query accordingly to save to the database.

Comment: ok i a not sure what you mean my run mysl escape string. this is what i am doign at the last page:  $_SESSION['options'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['options']);


foreach($_POST['options'] as &$options){
   mysql_real_escape_string($options);
}

Comment: @Humphrey: Instead of escaping, I recommend using parameterized queries in PDO. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use for checkboxes when inserting into database.

```
function validateCheckBox($name) {
    if (isset($_POST[$name]) && !empty($_POST[$name]) && $_POST[$name] === 'on') {
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No idea if you just typed this up, or you have no idea it's there

```
$_SESSION['SOME_OTHER_VALUE_FROM_TEXT_BOX'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_PSOT['SOME_OTHER_VALUE_FROM_TEXT_BOX');
```

should be

```
$_SESSION['SOME_OTHER_VALUE_FROM_TEXT_BOX'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SOME_OTHER_VALUE_FROM_TEXT_BOX');
```

Comment: Its correct in the question, in F21's answer its incorrect. Commenting that answer instead posting new answer would be the correct way.